# how to send a POST API on talend

Tags: api, talend, talend-mdm

I have an post API request that I want to send using talend.
With the API I need to send a body and 3n headers.
any idea which component I should use and how should I send the Json body and the headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tRestClient you should be able to send your post request with headers. Input row ou your tRestClient should contain a field name "body" which contains your json document.
Headers are in the advanced parameters of tRestClient.

Comment: how can I give the body to tRestClient
i have input schema but i cant define the body

Comment: place a tXMLMap component before the tRestClient , you will be able to define the schema as a Document in it

Comment: i have one more question about jsonpath can you help me wirh that